# Mail Server with different IP than Web Server

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, email-server, mx-record

I recently had a problem. Somebody hacked a Wordpress Site of one of my customers and sent about 70.000 Spam Emails. So my Server IP got blacklisted on some Providers.

I'm looking now for a solution to send my emails through another Mail Server with a different IP.

**My first question is**: Is it possible to have different IPs for Web Server and Mail Server or will the E-Mails get marked as Spam?

**My second question**: If it's possible, how can I configure ISPConfig or Postfix to make realize that?

The other solution would be to clone my server completely but I think that's not a good one...

Comment: 1) yes, this is very common as mail/web server can be on different servers 2) on `/etc/postfix/main.cf` for postfix set the `smtp_bind_address` to whatever IP is available. Note that id you fixed your spamming issue you can request to be lifted from the blacklists

Comment: Most blacklists will lift the ban on your IP usually within 24-48 hours after the spam emails have ceased.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you can do this by either having a separate NIC (network card) or by adding an additional IP to your current NIC.  The exact way of doing this is dependant on your OS but I would hope google would be your friend in helping out how to do that
2. I am not an expert but a quick google would suggest you can change the smtp_bind_address  entry in /etc/postfix/main.cf and then restart Postfix in order to use a specific IP when sending (you can also change inet_interfaces to set the IP you listen on to receive emails).

You should also make sure you start the process of getting the IP un-blacklisted as you never know when it might be needed in the future!

Comment: I already started unblacklisting and most of the lists deleted the ip from the blacklist. But still there are few BL left...

Comment: My problem with the IP is, that my Server has no second IP available, so I think the solution with smtp_bind_address will not work. The only thing I can do is to use another server. But this server also needs to have postfix installed and communicate with my postfix on the first server. How can I do that? (Or is there a more simple solution?)

Comment: you need to get an extra IP from your ISP, should be cheaper than a whole new server

Comment: I tried. But my Reason "Server abused for Spam" was not OK for the RIPE. Which kind of reason would be okay for that?